# How to fix the problem of a router not working in users.js but works in index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, router

I was trying to log every post request to the path /users.
This is my users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/users', function(req, res, next){
  console.log("POST from a user");
  res.send("task 2-2 called");
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, when I make a POST request to /users, a "Not found" error is shown.

When I put the same router in index.js, it works just fine.
How can I fix this?

Comment: your get `/` path works too? also can you show how you send your post request?

Comment: Please show your frontend work

Comment: Where do you use this router file?

Comment: Thank you both for answering, I found where the problem is. I was trying to include both /users and all the subpaths of it. I solved the problem by using /* as the path